# Writing unit tests with omitting some methods inside a method and also some conditions on method being tested

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, rhino-mocks

How to write tests that escapes or bypasses few methods and conditions inside a big method that is being tested.

For example, I have this method below:

```
public bool IsValid(int id)
{

 var details = _myService.GetDetails(id); // This line should be avoided in test
 var doctorDetails = _myService.GetDoctorDetails("AUS"); // This needs to be executed

if(details.Name == "Ab") // This if I dont want to be part of my test
{
 // Do something

}

if(doctorDetails !=null )
{
// Code to test

}

}
```

Edited my code, I need only the second IF statement to be tested in my method. I need to harcode the value of doctorDetails against to fetching its data from service as indicated above, because, for getting it from service, there should be details present, but it is not. Otherwise, only option is to mock it and store details in DB and call this service, which I do not want to do for now

Comment: @GrantWinney: I am new to testing, Yes, I think, how to write test for my requirement, please help me with code

Comment: @GrantWinney: My simple question is, how to hardcode bvalue of doctordetails ratehr than fetching it from service and then test only the second if statement. Doctordetails is just a string value

Answer (score 1):

The concept is that we need to be able to stub out other services so we can perform the execution of the second IF statement. Note that we do not want to talk to real services as it defeats the purpose of a Unit Test. I'm sorry I'm not sure the exact behaviour you intended to Unit Test, however hopefully below will point you to the right direction.

```
public class PatiantDetail {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorDetail {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IService {
    PatiantDetail GetPatiantDetail(int id);
    DoctorDetail GetDoctorDetail(string countryCode);
}

//System Under Test
public class Sut
{
    private readonly IService _myService;

    public Sut(IService service)
    {
        _myService = service;
    }

    public bool IsValid(int id)
    {
        var details = _myService.GetPatiantDetail(id); // This line should be avoided in test
        var doctorDetails = _myService.GetDoctorDetail("AUS"); // This needs to be executed

        if (details.Name == "Ab") // This if I don't want to be part of my test
        { // Do something 
        }

        if (doctorDetails != null)
        {// Code to test
        }

        return true;
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodForDemostationOfStubbing()
    {
        //Qustion: "How to write tests that escapes or bypasses few methods and conditions inside a big method that is being tested"
        //Answer:
        //This is pivotal to Unit Testing as we should be able to isolate dependencies and test what is only reequired. 
        //As soon as we concern about calling real services/db, it becomes an Integration Test :)
        //There are many ways to do isolate dependencies in your test. For example, 
        //  a. Poor man's techniques. (too much code you may have to write)
        //  b. Using an isolation framework. i.e Rhyno Mock you already using. (less code you have to write)


        //Using your example
        //"I need only the second IF statement to be tested in my method."

        //Arrange
        int id = 3;
        var stubService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
        stubService.Expect(x => x.GetPatiantDetail(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(new PatiantDetail() {Name = ""}); //so the first *if* statement get bypass. i.e not to return "Ab"

        //"I need to harcode the value of doctorDetails against to fetching its data from service as indicated above"
        stubService.Expect(x => x.GetDoctorDetail(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return(new DoctorDetail()); //returns an object with any hard coded data so the second *if* statement get executed.


        var sut = new Sut(stubService);

        //Act
        var isValid = sut.IsValid(id);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
    }
}
```